# Is it possible to Import Azure DevOps Work Items

Tags: azure-devops

We've moved to Azure and our code repository is currently in Azure DevOps.  We would like to start running our project management on the platform as well to better bind and track work items with changes, builds, and releases.

We have a large backlog of items that we have kept in Evernote and process out to Excel regularly.  Is it possible to import a bulk list of Work Items into the system?  I'd like to transfer items from my Excel spreadsheet into AzDevOp but I don't see anything on the form that seems to allow this.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You need to install the Visual Studio (with Team Explorer installed) or [Team Foundation Server Office® Integration 2017](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#team-foundation-server-office-integration-2015-update-3-1)

Please see [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=vsts) for details.

Comment: How do you import work items if you don't use Windows ? Is there a web interface to import data like you can in Jira ?

Comment: Please note (just like I discovered last week) that a Bulk modification with Excel won't let you import images (as part of e.g. the Description field). Images can only be imported as attachments.